# How can I protect open source against (mis)use by AI?

Tags: web-crawler, artificial-intelligence, open-source

As of 2023, there's a bunch of (Generative) AI available for public use; usually, they're re-constructing the most likely sequence of symbols for a given context.

**Which technical means exist to keep well-behaved (generative) AI from using my open source code?**

For web content, once can set robots.txt / the robots META tags, which (again, well-behaved) crawlers honour.

Which effective means exist that AI crawlers would honour?

(I've been rephrasing this question, since my earlier wording was not understood too often. I'm OK with anything technical that works - whether metadata, keywords, license files or headers, whatever. No legal advice wanted!)

Comment: Would the downvoters please explain their reasons? I'm asking a honest question here.

Comment: I started to write a genuine answer to this question, but then I stopped when I realized there's no way to answer this question without giving legal advice. You are asking for legal advice on the internet, even if it wasn't your intention to do so. Please talk to a lawyer.

Comment: I am not asking for *legal* advice. I am asking for technical means!  If I asked the same about web crawlers, answering with "here's the robots.txt standard" wouldn't be legal advice, either.

Comment: You are asking which license you should use to protect your code against being used to train a neural network; that is, you are asking which license you should use that would allow you to sue anyone who uses your code in such a manner.  Answering your question would constitute giving legal advice.

Comment: No, I have not asked "which license" or legal advice. I have asked for effective means, not limiting which these are - whether a special file like robots.txt, a special tag or phrase placed in comments, *or* a license whatever. My question is about something that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality you can not effectively safeguard your code (or anything else) from being used and consumed in AI systems. (That's the short and pessimistic answer.)

I still want to give it a shot:

---

**On the technical side:**

Most AI systems pick data up by crawling the internet, parsing existing libraries (for example language files, source code repositories, data sets, etc.), databases, etc. Of course this becomes much easier if you are Google or Microsoft and have a search engine with full internet cache located in the basement.

As to my knowledge there are no specific markers or similar (as you mention as a parallel to robots.txt or other), which tells an AI to back off and leave the premises. It is a nice idea, which might gain traction within the next few years. However, it requires a standardized way to store this metadata together with many different types of data on many different platforms and environments.

For now, I guess the only way to limit usage is to lock your code (or other information/text/data) up in a closed repository which has "members only" access. Carefully reading through the license terms of Github and other services out there could be interesting. -- Just because something is closed doesn't necessarily mean that the owner doesn't use the contents for AI purposes. (Github might be fine, but I haven't checked, so I really don't know.)

You might be able to find some nice services out there, which are particularly aware of these issues. This would probably be my best advice.

---

**On the legal side (already mentioned):**

Even if you picked a specific license and added an addendum to this stipulating specific limitations towards AI usage, this is no guarantee for anything.

Of course, the AI system owner might do something wrong when violating your license terms, but you would need to proove your case. In an international world, this becomes even more difficult.

---

**Wrapping up:**

You would need to combine the two dimensions, so you have a technical dimension preventing AI systems from picking up your stuff, and add a legal dimension to it in the form of a suitable license on top, which you could pull out of your hat in case disaster strikes.

Just my two cents. Hopefully this provides you with some ideas on how to solve the problem.

Cheers! :-)

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

As previous commenters have said, we'd need both the technical and legal aspects to be covered to be effective. I can't speak to the legal, but if we're talking about source code, it may be possible to embed values in otherwise unused variables that would identify your code. If AI passes the code 'as-is', those variables would be passed also.

As to whether this would have any affect on your being able to seek compensation for AI using unlicensed code, it would depend on the attorney, the amount sought and the time/difficulty to litigate the case.

This is a very 'iffy' proposition. As of now, there are no specific laws dealing with AI scraping and the corporations doing the scraping are big and powerful with a deep legal bench, so while attorneys might be glad to take your money for consulting, fewer would be willing to go out on a limb for possibly years, with nothing more than a promise of commission.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no specific license to prevent AI usage of code. If you want to restrict AI use, you may create a custom license. But making a new license needs legal expertise to be effective. Custom licenses may not be well-known like MIT, GPL, or Apache licenses that developers prefer for compatibility. Consider the balance between your intentions and practicality when deciding on a custom license for AI restrictions.

Comment: As long as the AI do not heed the licenses, no license terms will effectively have any effect.

Comment: So, the license is only for humans, right? I think for AI to crawl open source, it must also adhere to licenses.

Answer (score 0):

In any system it will be hard to protect your open-source data from misinformation with the use of AI. Having a firewall in place might limit misinformation. But like any technological system there is always a way to get around it. However, AI gives you a generalize template. For instance, in the healthcare system it could be a patient's medical record, age, weight, height and body mass index.
Hope this information helps!